# Possible synchronization issue due to code rearrangement by compiler

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized, volatile

Consider the following code sample:

```
private Object lock = new Object();
private volatile boolean doWait = true;

public void conditionalWait() throws Exception {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (doWait) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}

public void cancelWait() throws Exception {
    doWait = false;
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

If I understand the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) correctly, then above code is not Thread-safe. It might very well block because the compiler might decide to rearrange the code as follows:

```
public void cancelWait() throws Exception {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
    doWait = false;
}
```

In this case it might happen that thread T1 calls the `cancelWait()` method, aquire the lock, call `notifyAll()` and release lock. After this a parallel thread T2 could call `conditionalWait()` and aquire the now available lock. The variable `doWait` still has value true, thus thread T2 executes `lock.wait()` and blocks.

Is my understanding correct? If not, then please provide according references from the Java Specification which disprove above scenario.

Is there a solution that resolves this issue that does **not** require pulling `doWait` into the synchronized block?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as it stands, wouldn't any thread that calls conditionalWait (when doWait is true) have to wait indefinitely? cancelWait tries to acquire the lock on the same object that is locked from conditionalWait, so notifyAll can never be executed.

Comment: @user1431765 `wait()` releases the lock, so other threads can acquire the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken, but not because of reordering or visibility issues. Reordering problems occur in the absence of sufficient synchronization, which is not the case here. You have done everything possible, in terms of marking things volatile or synchronized, to let the JVM know to make the right things visible across threads.

Your problem here is that you're making several false assumptions:

- You're thinking wait can never return until it gets a notification (this may not happen frequently, but it can happen, this is called a "spurious wakeup").
- You're assuming that another thread can't barge in between the time the notification happens and the time that the waiting thread can reacquire the monitor. (Object#wait releases the monitor, and upon reacquiring it the thread needs to re-check what the current state is, instead of proceeding based on possibly outdated assumptions.)
- You're assuming you can predict that the notify will happen after the wait (can't say whether that's true in this case since you didn't post a complete working example, but in general this is not something you want to assume).

There are lots of toy examples (thinking of the even-odd assignment) that get away with this because they are limited to only 2 threads, the race condition that causes spurious wakeups doesn't happen often on PC JVMs, and the program forces the two threads to act in lock-step so the order in which things happen is predictable. But those aren't realistic assumptions for the real world.

The fix for these bad assumptions is to wait in a loop using a condition variable to decide when you're done waiting (see [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)):

```
private final Object lock = new Object(); // final to emphasize this shouldn't change
private volatile boolean doWait = true;

public void conditionalWait() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (doWait) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}

public void cancelWait() {
    doWait = false;
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

(I narrowed the exceptions thrown, the only thing thrown by notifyAll is IllegalMonitorStateException, which is unchecked and won't happen as long as you're using the right locks, it's only thrown as a result of programmer error.
Object#wait throws InterruptedException as well as IllegalMonitorStateException, it's ok to let it be thrown here.)

It would be just as well here to move the references to the doWait variable into the synchronized blocks, if all references to it are made while holding a lock then you don't need to make it volatile. But this isn't required.

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking is actually

> Can a monitor enter be re-ordered above a volatile store?

No, your transformation cannot happen. Take a look at the grid linked at the top of http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html.

```
First Operation:  Volatile Store
Second Operation: Monitor Enter
Result: No
```

So the compiler cannot re-order as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The Java memory model guarantees *sequential consistency* when your program is correctly synchronized.  Since your code above is correctly synchronized, then the reordering doesn't happen.

[Happens Before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> A program is correctly synchronized if and only if all sequentially consistent executions are free of data races.
>
> If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent (§17.4.3).
>
> This is an extremely strong guarantee for programmers. Programmers do not need to reason about reorderings to determine that their code contains data races. Therefore they do not need to reason about reorderings when determining whether their code is correctly synchronized. Once the determination that the code is correctly synchronized is made, the programmer does not need to worry that reorderings will affect his or her code.

This can be confusing since *sequential consistency* is defined previously in the inter-thread section of the spec (dealing with only a single thread).

[Programs and Program Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)

> A set of actions is sequentially consistent if all actions occur in a total order (the execution order) that is consistent with program order, and furthermore, each read r of a variable v sees the value written by the write w to v such that:
>
> w comes before r in the execution order, and
>
> there is no other write w' such that w comes before w' and w' comes before r in the execution order.
>
> Sequential consistency is a very strong guarantee that is made about visibility and ordering in an execution of a program. Within a sequentially consistent execution, there is a total order over all individual actions (such as reads and writes) which is consistent with the order of the program, and each individual action is atomic and is immediately visible to every thread.
>
> If a program has no data races, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent.

So what sequential consistency boils down to is that your program, when correctly synchronized, must appear to work like each read and write was completed exactly in the order specified in your program.  No reordering are allowed (or allowed to be visible).

Normally when you talk about a write being reordered you're talking about a p-threads memory model, used by C++ (I think), which specifies when writes can and cannot be re-ordered past a memory barrier.  It's a popular memory model and a lot of people know it.

Java doesn't have the concept of memory barriers.  Java is similar, but not the same as, the p-thread spec, so don't get the two confused.  In Java, either you have a program that works exactly in the order you specify in your program, or you have no guarantees at all if you don't synchronize.  It's one or the other, and your case the write to the volatile has to appear in program order.

---

Re. your question in your comment below:  I don't think it's that hard to find *happens-before* in the spec.  [Synchronization Order](http://well-of-souls.com/outsider/) says:

> Every execution has a synchronization order. A synchronization order is a total order over all of the synchronization actions of an execution. For each thread t, the synchronization order of the synchronization actions (§17.4.2) in t is consistent with the program order (§17.4.3) of t.
>
> Synchronization actions induce the synchronized-with relation on actions, defined as follows:
>
> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

And back to some definitions in [Happens Before Order:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).

So, the unlock of your monitor `synchronized (lock)` in `cancelWait()` *synchronizes-with* the lock acquire action in `conditionalWait()`.  *Synchroizes-with* creates a *happens-before* relationship (see the very last line of that quote directly above).  Therefore the assignment of `doWait=false;` must be visible when it is read in `conditionalWait()`.

(Happens Before Order also says:

> If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

so we know that if the volatile is assigned before the lock release, and a new lock acquire then happens after the lock release, it must be that the volatile assignment happens-before the lock acquire and is therefore visible.)

Comment: Can you actually point out the part of the Spec that says that the volatility of doWait establishes a happens-before relationship to the synchronized block? AFAIK, it only establishes a happens-before relationship to subsequent reads. So the compiler might still rearrange it as described.

Answer (score -1):

According JSL specification it's impossible
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

also you could look into 
[Java memory model : compiler rearranging code lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742333/java-memory-model-compiler-rearranging-code-lines)
http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile